# Twig - how to include a variable within a route in a form tag

Tags: twig, slim

I have the following in my form

```
<form action="{{ path_for('process', {'id': {{id}} }) }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

where {{id}} is a variable, but this causes an twig syntax error:

A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".

How can I include the variable with the path?

Answer (score 0):

Found how.

```
<form action="{{ path_for('process', {'id': id }) }}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```